# WebView and ActionBarSherlock Dynamic Progress Bar that follow url loading?

Tags: android, webview, progress-bar, android-actionbar

Here the code from ABS sample progress bar that update according to web loading by using `ActionBar` `ProgressBar`, the thing is the progress bar finishes before the page is loaded. Can anybody help correct this code?

```
private int mProgress = 100;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable mProgressRunner = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mProgress += 1;

        //Normalize our progress along the progress bar's scale
        int progress = (Window.PROGRESS_END - Window.PROGRESS_START) / 100 * mProgress;
        setSupportProgress(progress);

        if (mProgress < 100) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(mProgressRunner, 50);
        }
    }
};
```

---

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        if (mProgress == 100) {
            mProgress = 1;
            setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            mProgressRunner.run();
        } else {
            setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        }
    }
});
```